# r: set labels for every point in xyplot {lattice} not for groups

Tags: r, plot, label, point, lattice

I am sure there is a simple solution for my question but I couldn't find my answer. I would like to **put labels for every point value in scatterplot** using lattice, not the basic plot. I found that the  `library(direct.label)` can complete this work, nice example here: http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org/examples.html. 
However, the labels here are displaying the name of the group, not display the value/name for every point! **I would like to keep my data separated by groups (virginica, versicolor, setosa) but also add there exact value for every point (p.ex. Petal.Width) in the graph.** Please, how to complete this? 
Thank you a lot !

```
library(lattice)
trellis.par.set(standard.theme(color=FALSE))
p <- xyplot(jitter(Sepal.Length)~jitter(Petal.Length),iris,groups=Species)
direct.label(p)
```

what I do expect (the red values generated for every point):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `panel.text` inside `trellis.focus` like this:

```
p<-xyplot(jitter(Sepal.Length)~jitter(Petal.Length),iris,groups=Species)
p
trellis.focus("panel",1,1)
panel.text(x=p$panel.args[[1]]$x,y=p$panel.args[[1]]$y,labels = iris$Petal.Width, pos=3, cex=0.7, col="red")
trellis.unfocus()
```

[image]